# Show places on map upon selecting context menu options

Tags: android, dictionary, contextmenu, mapactivity, geopoints

I'm making a simple app using google maps, I have a context menu in the middle of the map and I want to show places, upon selecting one of the context menu options (the menu items have listeners which upon selection should trigger a request for webservice and then display the result on the map).
what is the correct way to do it should i pass an argument from the context menu activity to the mapactivity and check it on the mapactivity onResume() or is there some simpler way? 
i would be more happy if you have some written guide or code examples.

p.s
In terms of performance, since i want to store the webservice result to SQLite instance where should i insert the result to the db?